# Pattern matching between two files

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have two files: file1 and file2

file1:

```
1,0,0
2,1,2
```

file2:

```
abc gdksjhkjhfkdjfljdkjldk jkm kl;lll (sds; dks; id:1;)
zxc erefdjhfkdjfljdkjldk  erewr jkm kl;lll (sds; dks; id:2;)
```

output:

```
#abc gdksjhkjhfkdjfljdkjldk jkm kl;lll (sds; dks; id:1;)
zxc erefdjhfkdjfljdkjldk  erewr jkm kl;lll (sds; dks; id:2;)
```

If the number after id in file2 matches with first column of file1,

```
then: if third column in file1 is 0,print $1 of file2=abc else $1 of file=zxc
      if second column in file1 is 0,insert # at beginning
```

Another case
file1:

```
1,0,0
3,1,2
```

file2:

```
abc gdksjhkjhfkdjfljdkjldk jkm kl;lll (sds; dks; id:1;)
zxc erefdjhfkdjfljdkjldk  erewr jkm kl;lll (ders; dks; id:2;)
sdsd sdsdsdsddddsdjldk  vbvewqr dsm wwl;awww (cvv; fgs; id:3;)

Sometimes,the files will contain different number of lines.
In that case,if column one in file1 does not match with id in file2,it has to continue checking with next line in file2
```

How is it possible to do matching and modifying without merging two files with shellscript ?

Comment: Is the last if included in the first one or separate?

Comment: included in first one

Comment: Can you post what the desired output you're looking for is?

Comment: Well I thought you meant `$1` of file 1, as the first column but with `print $1 in file2=a else $1 in file=b` I'm completely lost now.

Comment: it is $1 of file1,sorry

Comment: If in file1,there are 2 rows and in file2 there are 3 rows each with different id: if id in third row of file2 is not present in file1,is there an option not to get it printed in file2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GNU `awk` 4**

Use this awk script:

```
FNR==NR{
    arr[FNR][1] = $1
    arr[FNR][2] = $2
    arr[FNR][3] = $3
}
FNR!=NR{
    val = gensub(/.*id:([0-9]+)[^0-9]*.*/, "\\1", "g", $0)
    if (arr[FNR][1] == val) {
        if (arr[FNR][2] == 0)
            printf "#"
        if (arr[FNR][3] == 0)
            $1 = "a"
        else
            $2 = "b"
    }
    print $0
}
```

Invoke it using: `awk -F '[, ]' -f script.awk file1 file2`

**GNU `awk` 3**

In an attempt to make the script work for earlier versions of `awk`:

```
# This awk script will perform these checks for EVERY single line:

# when FNR == NR we are in the first file
# FNR is the line number of the current file
# NR is the total number of lines passed
FNR==NR{
    # save the line of file1 to array with index it's line number
    arr[FNR] = $0
}
# we are now in file 2, because FNR could be 1 but NR is now 1 + lines
# in file 1
FNR!=NR{
    # create an array by splitting the corresponding line of file 1
    # we split using a comma: 0,1,2 => [0, 1, 2]
    split(arr[FNR], vals, ",")
    # use regex to extract the id number, we drop everything from the
    # line besides the number after "id:"
    val = gensub(/.*id:([0-9]+)[^0-9]*.*/, "\\1", "g", $0)
    # if first value of line in file1 is same as ID
    if (vals[1] == val) {
        # if second value of line in file1 is 0
        if (vals[2] == 0)
            # print # at beginning of line without adding a newline
            printf "#"
         # if third value of line in file1 is 0
        if (vals[3] == 0)
            # save "a" to var, else
            var = "a"
        else
            # save "b" to var
            var = "b"
    }
    # now sub the first word of the line [^ \t]* by var
    # and keep everything that follows (...) = \\1
    # the current line is $0
    # and print this modified line (now it's printed with a newline)
    print gensub(/^[^ \t]*([ \t].*)/, var "\\1", "g", $0)
}
```

Which is simply run as:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: Sorry,can you please see the output pasted above. All the modifications are to be done in file2

Comment: Can you verify output please?

Comment: arr[FNR][1] = $1    ^ syntax error. why could it be ?

Comment: Try again using `-F [, ]` although this script shouldn't error as it doesn't here...

Comment: Run `awk --version | head -n1` please, and paste the output.

Comment: version is GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: Is this your system? Can you update `awk` to 4.0.1? i.e. `sudo apt-get install gawk`.

Comment: If you add `arr[FNR] = $0` before the erroneous line, do you get a syntax error on the new line?

Comment: Still errror. awk: script.awk:3:     arr[FNR][1] = $1
awk: script.awk:3:             ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:4:     arr[FNR][2] = $2
awk: script.awk:4:             ^ syntax error
awk: script.awk:5:     arr[FNR][3] = $3
awk: script.awk:5:             ^ syntax error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79010/discussion-between-shellfish-and-user3823859).

Comment: If in file1,there are 2 rows and in file2 there are 3 rows each with different id: if id in third row of file2 is not present in file1,is there an option not to get it printed in file2